# Assignment inside const{} is not working when trying to assign values from this.props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

```
render() {
    const { type, id = this.id, className,
     value = this.state.value, required, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <input
        id={id}
        name={id}
        className={className}
        required={required}
        aria-required={required}
        type={type}
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        {...otherProps}
      />
    );
  }
```

I am trying to assign the 'id' and 'value' const variable to 'this.id' and 'this.state.value' respectively, but the values are not getting assigned, instead those values are getting assigned from the values which are getting passed from this.props.

I am in a use case where componentWillMount() and handleChange() functions use the 'pros.id' and 'props.value' to calculate some new values which will be assigned to 'this.id' and 'this.state.value'. Hence in the above code I needed the 'id' and 'value' to take from 'this.id' and 'this.state.vale' respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` in destructuring means assignment of default value (if no value is provided for key in object which is destructured). E.g:

```
const { key1 = 1, key2 = 2 } = { key1: 0 };
console.log(key1); // 0
console.log(key2); // 2
```

In your case you can destructure each object separately to initialize variables:

```
const { type, className, required, ...otherProps } = this.props;
const { id } = this;
const { value } = this.state;
```

If you want to omit `id` and `value` from `otherProps`, you can destructure it with another name. For example I assign it to the variables with name `_id` and `_value`:

```
const {
  type, className, required,
  id: _id, value: _value, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  ...otherProps
} = this.props;
const { id } = this;
const { value } = this.state;
```

Comment: If I try to use the above logic, 'id' and 'value' will be part of 'otherProps', which should not happen in my case.

Comment: Sorry I missed to say that we are using ESLint, which throws an error when a variable is assigned a value and never used.
In the above mentioned code '_id' and '_value' are assigned a value and never used.

Comment: @Bharath.N.V you can disable that warning with comment. See the update

Answer (score 0):

You're destructuring `this.props` into the variables, and the syntax you've used will only assign `this.id` to `id` when `this.props.id` is not present. Use of `=` in destructuring is for providing a default value when the value is not present in the destructured object (so in this example `this.id` will only be assigned to `id` when `this.props.id` does not exist).

You should remove `id` from the object destructuring call. If you want to provide a fallback option to use `id` from props then you could to this:

```
const id = this.id || this.props.id;
```

Comment: The important part of my use case is that I need the 'otherProps' to be passed to <input />, hence if I separately get the 'id' instead of the logic which I have mentioned in the question, the 'id' will be part of 'otherProps', which in my case should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
const {type, id: this.id, className, value: this.state.value, required, ...otherProps} = this.props;
//             ^                          ^
```

The `:` separates property name and assignment target, the `=` is used for default initialisers. Your syntax did take the value from `this.id` and assigned it to the `id` variable when there was no `id` property in `this.props`.

Comment: No, tried the logic which you have mentioned, the 'id' and 'value' will be part of 'otherProps' which should not happen in my case.

Comment: @Bharath.N.V Ah, I had it backwards; I thought you wanted to assign `const id = this.id` - mistook "to" for "from".